# Clients getting server ip as their default gateway

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a problem to solve.

**Scenario**:

```
LAN network 192.168.190.0/255 (1 server, 60 clients)

Server Windows 2008 (server roles: mail server, print server, dhcp server...etc)

5 pxe-clients

Debian Linux server
```

A few days ago I installed another server (Linux Debian) whose purpose is to work as a pxe server. The pxe server's main duty is to handle 5 clients for pxe network booting only (the clients belong to the same LAN as mentioned above). Everything seemed to work fine, but unfortunately I surprisingly found out that a few problems were just around the corner. Despite the fact I gave the server (Debian) a static ip, subnet and gateway, two out of the five pxe-clients got the Debian server ip as their default gateway. In a nutshell, the Debian server ip is 192.168.190.216 and its default gateway 192.168.190.254. Two pxe-clients got their own ip but they had the same gateway as 192.168.190.216 (Debian server ip) This of course prevented the pxe-clients from surfing the net.

**Questions**:

1. Does that sound unusual? I can't see the reason why some of the clients picked up the Debian server ip as their default gateway
2. Could I solve the problem by just setting up the Debian server to deal with a specific ip range, sort of subset of DHCP, (let's say 192.168.190.200/215) and let the rest of the subnet to the Windows server? (in order to avoid collisions) What I'm refering to is some kind of partitioning the network
3. If partitioning the network is regarded as the best choice, is VLAN the most appropriate implementation? In this case, can someone explain to me how VLAN works?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run two DHCP servers on the same layer 2 network.  That's a recipe for disaster.

The servers getting the wrong gateway mean that the DHCP server on your linux box isn't configured properly.  You should fix that.

But the bigger problem is that with two DHCP servers, you can never be sure which one will respond first.  Some PXE clients will get addresses from the windows server, and not PXE boot.  Other regular machines will get a DHCP address from the linux machine, and have problems as well.

VLANs are one way of solving it.  VLANs essentially carve one switch into a bunch of smaller switches.  So if I have a 48 port switch, and put ports 1-24 on VLAN1, and 25-47 on VLAN2, I now have pretty much the same as 2 separate 24 port switches.  Notice I didn't include port 48?  That port gets setup as a trunk containing both VLANs, and goes to my firewall.  The firewall can also handle VLANs, and provides internet access to both networks.  This way they remain separate, but I don't have to tie up 2 interfaces on the firewall and run 2 cables.  They function as separate networks, each with their own subnet (you could use the same for both, but it gets very confusing very quickly), their own DHCP and DNS servers, their own gateway, etc.  On the switch you assign each port to a particular VLAN.

The other option is using DHCP options 66 and 67 on the windows DHCP server to point PXE clients at the linux machine.  A simple google search for "linux pxe windows dhcp" turned up plenty of guides.  In this case, you would turn off the DHCP server on the linux machine, and just use the windows DHCP server.  This option is probably easier if you have no other reasons for having them on separate networks.

Comment: The DHCP server on the Debian host could be configured to only reply to specific MAC addresses. That way it won't be used by other hosts. The PXE clients should ignore the DHCP server which doesn't offer the necessary options. Combined that may be sufficient to ensure every host is served by the desired DHCP server. But having only a single DHCP server makes the behavior more predictable.

Comment: @kasperd that's true.  I left that option out because I've seen too many bad PXE implementations that don't work well with multiple DHCP servers.  And having to list all their MAC addresses will confuse the next guy when one of the PXE machines gets replaced.

Comment: @kasperd you are wrong; a PXE client will never ignore a DHCP offer if not complete (from a PXE point of view) as a proxyDHCP server offer arriving right after could very well complete the previous DHCP offer, and then, the client with the 2 offers gets all the reqd booting info. The solution to this problem does not require MAC filters, nor single DHCP servers, it just only needs to add a proxyDHCP to the original single DHCP scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your PXE server in "**proxyDHCP**" mode.
That way your Server Windows 2008 DHCP will be (as usual) in charge of assigning IPs, Default Gateways, and the like to "all" the clients (included PXE clients), and your proxyDHCP Server running at the Debian PXE server will provide the additional PXE related DHCP information  "only" to PXE booting clients. This "extra" DHCP information for PXE clients mainly consist of the name of the NBP file (Network Boot Program) and the IP of the TFTP server that hosts it (the Debian server in your case).

Then leave your current DHCP untouched and set a proxyDHCP in your Debian PXE server.

Running a DHCP server and a proxyDHCP server in the same sub-network is perfectly fine.